# Android:Display an image while page is loading using phonegap

Tags: java, android, cordova

How can I display an image for 2 seconds while loading page meanwhile?

```
public class MainActivity extends DroidGap  {

   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.loadUrl(url)
    }

}
```

I don't want to use the splashScreen plugin or js plugins.

something like run it as a thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you don't want to use the splashScreen plug-in, I'm guessing you are after the [Loader Widget](http://api.jquerymobile.com/loader/) which can take advantage of images.

Comment: I need to do in server side- before page is ready, and can't use jquery mobile plugin.